Running skaffold dev suddenly started taking forever to build and spin up containers
So up until a week ago running 'skaffold dev' was working the way I expected. It would immediately start building my containers and deploying them and when I had updates to my code it would immediately restart the containers with my new changes.
For some reason when I ran that same command in the same project folder I've been working on, it suddenly takes 10-30 minutes for skaffold to get past this one step
I am on a windows 11 machine
Generating tags...
 - niaporter/apiservice -> niaporter/apiservice:0e33b39-dirty
 - niaporter/mal-client -> niaporter/mal-client:0e33b39-dirty
Checking cache...

here's the version with vdebug
Generating tags...
 - niaporter/apiservice -> time="2024-07-11T18:09:39-07:00" level=debug msg="Running command: [git describe --tags --always]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:39-07:00" level=debug msg="Running command: [git describe --tags --always]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Command output: [0e33b39\n]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Command output: [0e33b39\n]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Running command: [git status . --porcelain]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Running command: [git status . --porcelain]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Command output: [ M testClient/src/App.tsx\n M testClient/src/hooks/useGetCredentials.ts\n]" subtask=-1 task=Build
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Command output: [ M package.json\n M skaffold.yaml\n M src/constants.ts\n M src/routes/ghl/internal/login.ts\n M testClient/src/App.tsx\n M testClient/src/hooks/useGetCredentials.ts\n M yarn.lock\n?? src/routes/algolia/\n]" subtask=-1 task=Build
niaporter/apiservice:0e33b39-dirty
 - niaporter/mal-client -> niaporter/mal-client:0e33b39-dirty
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=info msg="Tags generated in 240.6601ms" subtask=-1 task=Build
Checking cache...
time="2024-07-11T18:09:40-07:00" level=debug msg="Found dependencies for dockerfile: [{package.json /app true 4 4} {. /app true 7 7}]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2024-07-11T18:09:42-07:00" level=debug msg="Found dependencies for dockerfile: [{package.json /app true 6 6} {yarn.lock /app true 6 6} {. /app true 9 9}]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2024-07-11T18:09:42-07:00" level=debug msg="Could not import artifact from Docker, building instead (import of missing images disabled)" subtask=-1 task=Build

not sure what happened but it's infuriating every time I have to make even the smallest code change
for reference in case it's my setup
skaffold.yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta6
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: niaporter/apiservice
      context: .
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/***/*.ts'
            dest: .
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    - image: niaporter/mal-client
      context: testClient
      sync:
        infer:
        - '**/*.js'
        - '**/*.ts'
        - '**/*.tsx'
        - '**/*.scss'
        - '**/*.html'
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
  local:
    push: false
manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - ./infra/k8s/*
#    - ./infra/k8s-dev/*
deploy:
  kubectl: {}

apiservice dockerfile
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN yarn install --prod
COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

mal-client dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build the React application
FROM node:16 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . ./
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2: Serve the React application with nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

